# Normalizing a database column

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, database-normalization

The objective here is to be able to query a database providing it with a **Journey**, based on the **Journey** the database will return all of the **Stop Codes** that run through this journey.

So for example I need to be able to say, "Select all of the stop codes that run through journey 34". This should then only return STOP CODE: SZDASDASDE. (in production many more codes will be returned).

[image: http://i.imgur.com/9ZBSxmq.png]

Above you can see an image of the first table in a database.

[image]

You can also see the second table where each **STOP CODE** has many **JOURNEYS** as parents. As far as I know putting multiple journeys into a single field does not follow standard database design so if anyone can help me fix that I would really appreciate it.

These images were taken in Microsoft's Excel just to plan how I'm going to do this, production will be using a MySQL database.

Thanks

Comment: normalize, normalize, normalize

Comment: Hence "normalize" in the title ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a **many to many** relationship between Stop Codes and Journeys. To eradicate this, you need to decompose the relationship.

In order to do this, you need an intermediary table, let's call it JourneyStopCode, which will look like:

```
JourneyStopCode:
JourneyStopCodeID (primarykey)
JourneyID
StopCodeID
```

Then your Stop Code table wouldn't have a JourneyID field.

To retrieve stop codes for a journey, you'd do:

```
SELECT * FROM StopCode
INNER JOIN JourneyStopCode ON StopCode.StopCodeID = JourneyStopCode.StopCodeID
INNER JOIN Journey On Journey.JourneyID = JourneyStopCode.JourneyID
WHERE JourneyID = @yourJourneyID
```

**Edit: To visualise:**

```
---------------        ---------------------         ----------------
|  Journey    |        | JourneyStopCode   |         |  StopCode    |
---------------        ---------------------         ----------------
| JourneyID   |<---    | JourneyStopCodeID |     --->|  StopCodeID  |
| Description |   |----| JourneyID         |     |   |  Latitude    |
---------------        | StopCodeID        |------   |  Longitude   |
                       ---------------------         ----------------
```

Then your data would look like:

### Journey

```
----------------------------------------
| JourneyID | Description              | 
----------------------------------------
| 34        | Southampton - Portsmouth |
----------------------------------------
```

### StopCode

```
----------------------------------------
| StopID | Latitude | Longitude        | 
----------------------------------------
| SSDAFS | 12345    | 67890            |
----------------------------------------
```

### JourneyStopCode

```
------------------------------------------
| JourneyStopID | JourneyID | StopCodeID | 
------------------------------------------
| 1             | 34        | SSDAFS     |
------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you suggesting I need only a single table? I'd appreciate it if you could visualize your answer for me, I'm pretty knew to database design and am trying to get my head around your answer (which is probably right)

Comment: @JoelKidd If you check my edit, I've tried to visualise it better :).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much for putting so much detail in your answer, really helped me understand!

Comment: One question, in the JourneyStopCode table, what use is the JourneyStopCodeID column? Is it just there to act as a key?

Comment: @JoelKidd No problems! It's basically just a dummy column that you can use as a primary key, as you wouldn't be able to use one of the other fields as a primary key (you could use them both as a composite key however, but let's not go that far :)). You can remove it if you don't want a primary key in your table, but it's always best practice to have one.

Comment: That's great, thanks again. One last final question, would you be able to modify your query so that the query returns all of the stop's latitude and longitude positions? So basically I need a query that says, find me all the stops lat and lng positions where the journey code is 34 for example.

Comment: @JoelKidd That should be what my query is already giving you? Or are there multiple latitude/longitude values for a single stop?

Comment: Sorry you're right, my fault I misread the query! All is good, thanks!

Comment: @mattytommo - Malcolm Birtle would be proud.

Comment: @DarrenDavies LMAO, congrats on C# gold. Malcolm would be going mental, I've used IDs.

Comment: @mattytommo - ta. Haha yeah ooops! Annette would want ya to use a Left Anti Semi Join

Comment: @DarrenDavies Haha, I rang Reggie to discuss this, he said I needed an Element table.

Answer (score 3):

Journeys to stop codes is a many to many relation ship, you want a join table most likely.

```
Table 1 :
SID   |   Stop Code   |  Long    |   lat 
0     | ASDFSAFA      | 1        | 2
1     | sdDSGSDGS     | 4        | 0 
....

Table 2 : 
Journey   | Description 
0         | Blah blah blah


Table 3 : 
Journey  | SID 
0        |  1
2        |  1
1        |  4


SELECT A.Longitude, A.Latitude FROM TABLE1 WHERE A.SID IN (
    SELECT SID FROM TABLE3 WHERE JOURNEY = 0
);
```

Comment: Unless stop codes change, they could serve just fine as a PK.

Comment: Would you be able to show a SQL query that would return the latitude and longitude values of all stops where the journey passed is 0 for example?

Comment: Sure, thats very simple with a sub query . Ive added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    TABLE 1
    -------
    JOURNEY (PK) DESCRIPTION

    TABLE 2
    -------
    SEQUENCENO (PK) STOP_CODE LATITUDE LONGITUDE

    TABLE 3
    -------
    JOURNEY SEQUENCENNO
```